# Solution to harmonic oscillator with periodic forcing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Using matlab symbolic processor, I can get the homogenous and particular solution to a harmonic oscillator with periodic forcing.  I'm trying to write the particular solution in a compact form, with limited success. Does anyone have the general solution to a harmonic oscillator under periodic forcing?

Here's the equation I want to solve

$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} h(t) + 2 \zeta \omega_n \frac{d}{dt} h(t) + \omega_n^2 h(t) = \frac{C_i}{m} \sin(\omega_f t + \phi)
.
$$

Here's one approach

```
syms h(t) zeta omega_n h0 dh0 Cfi wfi phif m 
Dh(t)=diff(h(t),t);
eqs = diff(h(t), t, t) == -2*zeta*omega_n*Dh-omega_n*omega_n*h(t)+Cfi/m*sin(wfi*t+phif);
disp('equation')
pretty(eqs)
sol=dsolve(eqs, h(0)==h0, Dh(0)==dh0);
pretty(sol)
chk=simplify(diff(sol,t,t)+2*zeta*omega_n*diff(sol,t)+omega_n*omega_n*sol-Cfi/m*sin(wfi*t+phif));
disp('check solution, should be zero');
disp(chk)
```

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Sinusoidal_driving_force) has the equation you are looking for.  Note that you need not include the $\phi$ in the driving force as you can just choose the zero of time to make $\phi=0$.  The $\phi$ in the solution is the phase shift between the driving force and the response.

Comment: I saw the no phase solution, but I have multiple forcing frequencies so I need phase, and also the phase is nonzero.  But, now I see one solution is to simply to write the forcing as a cos and sin term instead of phase, and work solve the resulting harmonics.

Comment: In my problem, I actually have the time response, h.  I'm trying to determine the forcing.

Comment: Do you mean omega and Omega to be the same?  They should not be.  As you are using them, omega is the natural frequency of the undamped oscillator and Omega is the forcing frequency.  It is a bad idea to use them both unless you write MathJax because of possible confusion.

Comment: The omegas are meant to be different, omega is the undamped natural frequency, and Omega is the forcing frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $h(t)$ and want to find the forcing function, you can Fourrier analyze it. For each term $a \sin (\psi t)$ in the expansion, the left side becomes $a (\omega^2 -\psi^2)\sin (\psi t) +2a \zeta \omega \cos(\psi t)$  That matches the right side.

Comment: That just brings me back to the original question, because the phase is needed for each term.

Comment: I meant each forcing term.

Comment: You can combine the sine and cosine terms to give a sine with a phase.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to 
$$
h''(t)+2\zeta\omega_nh'(t)+\omega_n^2h(t)=\frac {C_i} m   cos(\Omega_i t + \phi_i)
$$
is better written as
$$
h''(t)+2\zeta\omega_nh'(t)+\omega_n^2h(t)=\frac {C_i} m cos(\Omega_i t) 
+ \frac {S_i} m sin(\Omega_i t)
$$
and solved using

```
syms zeta omega_n t A B w Cfi Sfi m 
sol = A * cos(w*t) + B * sin(w*t);
eqn1 = diff(sol,t,t) + 2 * zeta * omega_n * diff(sol,t) + omega_n^2 * sol - Sfi/m*sin(w*t)-Cfi/m*cos(w*t);
eqn1 = collect(eqn1,{cos(t*w),sin(t*w)});
expr_1 = children(eqn1);
expr_11 = children(expr_1(1));
expr_12 = children(expr_1(2));
solAB=solve({expr_11(1),expr_12(1)},{A,B});
disp('A');
pretty(solAB.A);
disp('B');
pretty(solAB.B);
disp('A cos + B sin')
pretty(solAB.A*cos(Omega_i*t)+solAB.B*sin(Omega_i*t));
chksoln = (cos(Omega_i*t)*(Cfi*(omega_n^2-Omega_i^2)-2*Sfi*zeta*Omega_i*omega_n) ...
    +sin(Omega_i*t)*(Sfi*(omega_n^2-Omega_i^2)+2*Cfi*zeta*Omega_i*omega_n)) ...
    /(m*((omega_n^2-Omega_i^2)^2+(2*zeta*Omega_i*omega_n)^2));
% chksoln = solAB.A*cos(Omega_i*t)+solAB.B*sin(Omega_i*t)
disp('this should be zero');
chkeqn1 = simplify(diff(chksoln,t,t) + 2 * zeta * omega_n * diff(chksoln,t) + omega_n^2 * chksoln - Sfi/m*sin(Omega_i*t)-Cfi/m*cos(Omega_i*t))
```

as

$$
h_P(t) = 
\frac{
\cos \left(\Omega_i t\right)
 \left(  C_i \left( {\omega_n}^2- {\Omega_i}^2 \right) - 2 S_i \zeta \Omega_i \omega_n \right)
+\sin \left(\Omega_i t\right)
 \left( S_i \left( {\omega_n}^2-{\Omega_i}^2 \right) + 2 C_i \zeta \Omega_i \omega_n \right)
}
{m \left({\left( {\omega_n}^2- {\Omega_i}^2 \right)}^2 + { \left(  2 \Omega_i \omega_n \zeta \right) }^2 \right)}
$$

Comment: The $\LaTeX$ seemed to get spoiled by the two blank lines near the end.  I took them out and it fixed things.